# Cannot read property 'location' of undefined when try to reload div in ionic

Tags: html, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a div that show something, I want to make that div can reload after I push a button, I make a function like this in my controller :

```
$scope.getdis = function () {
    document.getElementById('map').contentWindow.location.reload();
};
```

this is my full controller :

```
app.controller('discoverCtrl', function($scope, $timeout, $http, $location, $ionicPopup) {
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function() {

    $scope.initialise = function() {

      var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
      var mapOptions = {
      center: myLatlng,
      zoom: 13,
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);

    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(pos) {
        map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitude));
        var myLocation = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitude),
            map: map,
            clickable: true
        });
        var dparkings;
        dparkings = '{"dparking": {"cabang":[{"id":"1","place":"Aaaa", "type":"R", "x":"-6.2245609", "y":"106.8290384"},{"id":"2", "place":"Bbbb", "type":"P", "x":"-6.2272616", "y":"106.8241209 " }, {"id":"3", "place":"Cccc", "type":"P", "x":"-6.2239737", "y":"106.8248723"}, {"id":"4", "place":"Dddd", "type":"P", "x":"-6.2239737", "y":"106.829"}]}}';

        var msg = JSON.parse(dparkings);
        var gambar;
        for(i=0;i<msg.dparking.cabang.length;i++){
           if (msg.dparking.cabang[i].type=='P') {
              gambar = 'img/parking_on_small.png';
            }
            else if (msg.dparking.cabang[i].type=='R') {
              gambar = 'img/reserved_on_small.png';
            }
            var point = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(msg.dparking.cabang[i].x),parseFloat(msg.dparking.cabang[i].y));
                  tanda = new google.maps.Marker({
                  position: point,
                  map: map,
                  icon: gambar,
                  clickable: true,
                  title: msg.dparking.cabang[i].place
            });

        }

    });


    $scope.map = map;
    };
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById("map"), 'load', $scope.initialise());
  });
  //document.getElementById('map').contentWindow.location.reload();
  $scope.showmenu = function () {
  document.getElementById("leftpanels3").style.display = "block";
  $timeout(function(){
    document.getElementById("leftpanels3").style.display = "none";
    }, 3000);
  };

  $scope.closemenu = function () {
  document.getElementById("leftpanel3").style.display = "none";
  };

  //relogin($http, $location, '');
  $scope.rs_page = function () {
    displaylastreservation($http, $location, $ionicPopup);
  };
  $scope.godt = function () {
    $location.path('/reservation_place');
  };

  /*$scope.geourls = geourl;
  document.getElementById('ifr1').contentWindow.location.reload();
   $scope.getpark = function () {
    geourl = '#/geoloc_p';
    $scope.geourls = geourl;
    document.getElementById('ifr1').contentWindow.location.reload();

  };
  $scope.getres = function () {
    geourl = '#/geoloc_r';
    $scope.geourls = geourl;
    document.getElementById('ifr1').contentWindow.location.reload();
  };*/
  $scope.getdis = function () {
    geourl = '#/geoloc1';
    //$scope.geourls = geourl;

    document.getElementById('map').contentWindow.location.reload();
  };


});
```

this is my html :

```
<div data-role="page" class="ui-mobile-viewport ui-overlay-a jqm-demos ui-page ui-page-theme-a ui-page-active fonthel" data-quicklinks="true"  tabindex="0" style="min-height: 598px; width:100%;" ng-controller="discoverCtrl">

    <div data-role="header" class="col-header ui-header ui-bar-inherit" role="banner">
        <button class="btmenu" ng-click="showmenu()">

            <img src="img/hamburger-menu.png">
        </button>
        <h3 class="col-header-title ui-title" role="heading" aria-level="1" >Discover

        <table class="pull-right"><tbody><tr>
        <td width="40" align="center"><a href ="#/coupon" class="ui-link"><img src="img/icon-coupon.png" height="24px" ></a></td>
        <td width="40" align="center"><a class="ui-link" ng-click="rs_page()"><img src="img/icon-barcode.png" height="24px" ></a></td>
        </tr></tbody></table>
        </h3>
    </div><!-- /header -->


    <div class="dashboard-search clearfix">    

        <div class="pull-right">
            <a  class="ui-link" ng-click="getpark()"><img src="img/parking_on.png" class="icon30 vmargin5"></a>
            <a  class="ui-link" ng-click="getres()"><img src="img/reserved_on.png" class="icon30 vmargin5"></a>
        </div>

        <div class="input-group" style="width:65%">
          <div class="ui-input-text ui-body-inherit ui-corner-all ui-shadow-inset"><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Current location"></div>
          <span class="input-group-btn">
            <a  class="btn btn-white ui-link" ><img src="img/icon-search-map.png" class="icon20"></a>
          </span>
        </div><!-- /input-group -->

    </div>

    <div  role="main" class="ui-content jqm-content jqm-fullwidth" style="width: 100%; height: 500px; position: absolute;">

            <!--<div id='mapdiv' style="height:380px; width:100%"></div>  -->

            <div id="map" data-tap-disabled="true" style="width: 100%; height: 500px; position: absolute;"></div>




    </div><!-- /content -->



    <!----------------------
    ||   FOOTER
    ------------------------>
    <div class="footer clearfix" style="color:#fff">
        <ul class="list-btn-discover clearfix">
            <li><a class="active ui-link" ng-click="getdis()">Map View</a></li>
            <li><a  href="#/discover_list" style="color:#fff" class="ui-link">List View</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div><!-- /footer -->


</div><!-- /page -->



<!----------------------
||   LEFT Panel  
------------------------>

<div data-role="panel" name ="leftpanels3" id="leftpanels3" data-position="left" data-display="overlay" data-theme="a" style="text-shadow:0 0 0; padding:0;" class="ui-panel ui-panel-position-left ui-panel-display-overlay ui-body-a ui-panel-animate ui-panel-closed paneloverlay" >

    <div class="ui-panel-inner"><ul class="menu-icon">
        <li>
            <a href="#/discover">
                <img src="img/icon-discover.png" class="img-responsive">
                <div class="title">Discover</div>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a >
                <img src="img/icon-history.png" class="img-responsive">
                <div class="title">History</div>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a>
                <img src="img/icon-where_my_car.png" class="img-responsive">
                <div class="title">Mark my car</div>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a>
                <img src="img/icon-promotion.png" class="img-responsive">
                <div class="title">Promotions</div>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#/setting">
                <img src="img/icon-setting.png" class="img-responsive">
                <div class="title">Setting</div>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul></div>

</div>
<!-- /leftpanel3 -->
```

When I try to run it, this error show :

> Cannot read property 'location' of undefined

Yet when I used that code to reload iframe, it work, anybody can help ?

Comment: Post your controller

Comment: Please provide your html

Comment: Is your `map` element within an iframe?

Comment: @Sajeetharan I have edit and show my full controller

Comment: @AnikIslamAbhi I have provide my html

Comment: @tylerwal I not used iframe, but I ever tried to reload iframe and it worked

Comment: Can you provide a working fiddle with this problem? I'm sure that if we will see it we can answer you very quickly.